# How to map pairs of different URLs in a Lucene index and query against those?

Tags: java, lucene, text-mining

How it is possible to add URL mappings to Lucene and read them?

Store like: `url1 - url2`. And if you send query `url1` get `url2`. I used `PhraseQuery`, `TermQuery` and `FuzzyQuery` but couldn't get result.

For example:

> http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Mountain - http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Everst

Answer (score 0):

At index time, it is possible to add the urls in two separate fields: url1 searchable (indexed), and url2, just stored.

Assuming a more recent version of Lucene (at least 4):

```
    doc.add(new StringField("url1", url1String, Store.NO));
    doc.add(new StoredField("url2", url2String));
```

Comment: If 'url1' is not the default search field, set like QueryParser parser = new QueryParser('url1', analyzer) then you need to prefix the query with 'url1:'